# Effectively managing image resizing in PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I'm using a Symfony2 bundle from GregWar to resize up to 12 images at a time from a user upload. I'm using this https://github.com/Gregwar/ImageBundle

I'm resizing them to four different sizes, as these sizes are needed for mobile, desktop, thumbnail, etc. It takes time to do each one of course, but with 12 x 4 resizes it can take a while. Over 30 seconds easily. Which is behind the default PHP timeout and isn't really acceptable for an end user wait time.

I want the resizing to be done at upload so the new sizes are available immediately to the user. Rather than later as a batch process.

This seems like it may be a common problem. So what can I do to improve my situation?

Should I use a different library?

Or reduce my image sizes from four, down to perhaps two to improve processing speed but sacrifice user experience?

Is this normal? Could it be a hardware issue? On my local machine it's even slower.

PHP memory is set to 256MB. I use a ServerGrove VPS, with PHP5.3.

Comment: Are you currently using 'gd'? (it's nowhere in your question)

Comment: https://github.com/Gregwar/ImageBundle

Answer (score 0):

I have moved away from trying to solve this on my server and instead now use a dedicated EC2 instance with Amazon to resize images.

Similar to this approach http://sumitbirla.com/2011/11/how-to-build-a-scalable-caching-resizing-image-server/

Answer (score -1):

If there is [GD extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) installed on your server, you can use [`imagecopyresized`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php) function.